# react-hook-form doesn't work validation with custom input

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

when I just use <input {...register(name)} />, validation works correctly: empty required-fields give an error, when filled out, the error disappears. But if this input is moved to a separate component, does the error disappear when filled in?

Code:

**parent**:

```
<InputField
    validationType="underlineText"
    invalidText={errors?.[name]?.message}
    invalid={Boolean(errors?.[name]?.message)}
    {...register(name)}
/>
```

**InputField.tsx**:

```
export const InputField = memo(({
  invalid,
  invalidText,
  validationType,
  ...otherProps
}: IInputProps) => (
  <InputValidationWrapper
    invalid={invalid}
    invalidText={invalidText}
    validationType={validationType}
  >
    <input
      {...otherProps}
    />
  </InputValidationWrapper>
))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `react-hook-for` works with the `ref` of element, You need to wrap your custom component with `React.forwardRef`, like this:

```
const InputFieldRef = forwardRef(
  ({ invalid, invalidText, validationType, ...otherProps }, ref) => {
    return (
      <InputValidationWrapper
        invalid={invalid}
        invalidText={invalidText}
        validationType={validationType}
      >
        <input {...otherProps} ref={ref} />
      </InputValidationWrapper>
    );
  }
);

export const InputField = memo(InputFieldRef);
```

and here is example of using above component:

```
<InputField
        validationType="underlineText"
        invalidText={errors?.[name]?.message}
        invalid={Boolean(errors?.[name]?.message)}
        {...register(name, { required: "Field is Required" })}
/>
```